# Difference between 'getfacl' and 'ls -l'

Tags: linux, file-permissions, acl

What is the difference between
`getfacl` and `ls -l` in **Linux**?
Both of them produce output with the same content.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `getfacl(1)` man page:

> For  each  file,  getfacl displays the file name, owner, the group, and
>          the Access Control List (ACL). If a directory has a default  ACL,  get‐
>          facl also displays the default ACL. Non-directories cannot have default
>          ACLs.

Basically, `getfacl` is used to get the filename, the owners, and the file mode in a shell script friendly output. Unlike `ls`, which is used mainly to list directory contents.

Comment: getfacl also shows more permissions than ls. `ls` only shows traditional file mode permission, getfacl shows the access control list (ACL). ACL allows to set permissions for several groups and users and not only one.  see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364517/difference-between-chmod-vs-acl